# Private static variables in Swift don't compile in AppCode but it does in Xcode

Tags: swift, appcode

I have a class where I have a private static constant:

```
class A {

    private static let MY_CONSTANT = 1000

    func setUp (xAxis:Charts.XAxis) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also in this class I have a method (setUp), inside of that method I create another class which uses that constant:

```
func setUp (xAxis:Charts.XAxis) {

    class HistogramReadLenghtFormateer:IAxisValueFormatter {
        func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

            let lowIndex = Int(value) / A.MY_CONSTANT
            let topIndex = (Int(value) + A.MY_CONSTANT) / A.MY_CONSTANT
            return String(lowIndex) + "K" + "-" + String(topIndex) + "K"
        }
    }
    let histogramReadLenghtFormateer = HistogramReadLenghtFormateer()

    xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    xAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 6)
    xAxis.granularity = Double(A.MY_CONSTANT)
    xAxis.labelCount = 7
    xAxis.valueFormatter = histogramReadLenghtFormateer
}
```

Well, it seems that Xcode is ok with it, but AppCode complains:

> Cannon Access to MY_CONSTANT. It is private in A

I know it's private but the class is defined inside of a method of the class A.

But it's even more intriguing that one compiler complain and the other one doesn't.

I guess it's because some settings of some kind. Any idea where to change this?

Comment: Looks like you are using `A.MY_CONSTANT` in a couple of places, which lines are generating the errors? Are they the ones from the inner class `HistogramReadLenghtFormateer`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The ones generate errors are inside of the class `HistogramReadLenghtFormateer` in the method `stringForValue`

Comment: Then it could be that the Swift compiler used by AppCode to not allow private declarations within a class to be visible in inner classes. Try switching to `fileprivate`, this might fix the visibility issue.

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm using AppCode EAP 2019.1 with Xcode 10.1

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing isn't a compiler error, it's part of AppCode's own analysis, which is wrong in this case. (Sorry about that, I've created [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-18479) for you and will try to fix it soon.)

You should still be able to compile and run your project. If it doesn't, a different problem is causing it.